# My android app is not visible in Do Not Disturb exception list

Tags: android, do-not-disturb

I have developed a messaging app. It's live in play store. As this is a messaging app, I want user to be able to add this app in Do Not Disturb exception list. But my app is not visible in Do Not Disturb exception list.
I tried by adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />` in manifest file as well but still can't see my app in the list.

I also did lots of research on google but can't find appropriate solution for my problem. It will be great help if someone has proper information about this.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @JanErikSchlorf no, didn't find any solution.